# bsonxx::from_json convert all value types to string

Tags: c++, mongodb, bson, mongo-cxx-driver

I am using Boost's Property Tree library for storing my json files. For example,
 I have the following JSON file:

```
{
    "var" : true,
    "bar" : -1.56
}
```

Next I parse this file to `ptree` object, do my job and want to store output in MongoDB. For this I convert it back to JSON string:

```
boost::property_tree::ptree root;
boost::property_tree::read_json(file_path, root);
... // do my job
std::stringstream ss;
boost::property_tree::json_parser::write_json(ss, root);
std::string my_json_string = ss.str();
```

After this I push my results to MongoDB, by converting JSON string to BSON like this: `bsonxx::from_json(my_json_string)`. As result I receive the following entity in database:

```
{
    "var" : "true",
    "bar" : "-1.56"
}
```

Is there a way to insert my JSON string to MongoDB with persistence types?

Comment: What is the JSON in `my_json_string`?  How did you get the JSON text for what is in the database?  Without showing all the intermediate steps, there's no way to discover where the problem occurred.

Comment: This comes from this call: `std::string my_json_string = ss.str();`. It return a JSON string from Boost::PropertyTree. And it exactly what I need `"{"var":true;"bar":-1.56}"`

Comment: The JSON example you just gave has a typo in it (semicolon is not a valid field separator).  However, if I fix that and run it through bsoncxx::from_json, I get a valid BSON document and the "bar" field is type double.  In order to diagnose, I need more information.  What version of bsoncxx and libbson do you have installed?  What platform/OS?  Can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem that we can use for a reproduction?